# Linked list node with pointer to struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I am new to C programming. Familiarising muself with struct pointers and linekd lists. I came across concept of linked list node with pointer to struct.

```
typedef struct
{
   string name, surname;
   int matriculation_num;
}Student_typedef;

typedef struct
{
   Tstudent* student;
   Node_typedef* next;
} Node_typedef;
```

Can anyone tell me what exactly is the purpose of Node_typedef. Where are such implementations usefull ? 
Any useful link is much appreciated.

Comment: *"what exactly is the purpose of `Node_typedef`"* — in the code you posted? None really.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef

Comment: It stores data and a pointer to the next node. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list

Comment: What do you mean by "examples oeprations"? The usual would be "add/remove", "read/write", "sort", "find". Some of them require a slightly extended agree interface, which might mix both halfs of the separation, e.g. "find" requires a possibility to compare some part of the student info to a targer, while being able to iterate through the storage info.

Comment: So, Its more about managing list efficiently ? To defernce the Student_typdef, we would be using Node_typedef.student->name and  Node_typedef maintains the linked list with calue as pointer to Student_typedef ?

Answer (score 0):

The two shown struct type definitions separate the stored data from the storing mechanism.

You can see that `Student_typedef` has only members which relate to information to store, but none relating to storing. The goal is to have a mechanism which can store a multitude of this data structure.

On the other hand `Node_typedef` does not contain any of the information to store, only a single pointer to the complete data. If the structure of the inforamtion to store would change (though still be reflected by the same type identifier `Student_typedef`), then nothing about this storage mechanism would have to be changed.

Or to describe it from a different angle, two developers working on a student database would only have to agree that all the needed information for each student is inside `Student_typedef`. Then one developer could handle programming functions to enter or edit  a given struct (based on a pointer to the struct provided by the storage), while the other developer could handle storage aspects, like adding a new struct to fill, deleting, optimising memory, etc.

Such methods of interface definition and abstraction of code parts are necessary for efficiently handling large projects.